# apache weird error message encoding

Tags: windows, apache, command-line

I'm using Windows Command Line and Apache gives me the error in this encoding:

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 163 of Z:/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
ot load Z:/usr/local/php5/php5apache2_2.dll into server: %1 \xed\xe5 \xff\xb\xff\xe5\xf2\xf1\xff \xef\xf0\xe8\xeb\xee\xe6\xe5\xed\xe8\xe5\xec Win32.
```

I can't find the tool to convert the error message from this `\xed\xe5` to UTF-8. What encoding does Apache use?

Answer (score 0):

This Should change it to utf-8.

In httpd.conf add :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Make sure you put it at the bottom of the file so that it overrides pre-existing directives.

Hope that helps

Comment: This doesn't help since the directive is used when server is already running and for another purposes. thanks for bothering anyway